# How to render a tpl of a dataview with an external store?

Tags: javascript, load, extjs4, store, dataview

I am struggling with my view that i load with a store inside my page using a proxy, and its work perfectly. But as soon as I load the same dataview with the same srore but an extern one, it doesn't work.

This sample works :

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{

storeId:'employeeStore',
fields:['id', 'name', 'type','children'],
data:[
    {
        id : 1,
        name : "GEO ET 09",
        type : 1,
        children: [ 
            { id: 11, parent: 1 ,name: '0820 689 689' }, 
            { id: 12, parent: 1, name: '0820 689 689' },
            { id: 13, parent: 1 ,name: '0820 689 689' }, 
            { id: 14, parent: 1, name: '0820 689 689' },
        ]
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        name : "0800 & 0805",
        type : 2,
        children: [ 
            { id: 21, parent: 2, name: '0820 689 689' }, 
            { id: 22, parent: 2, name: '0820 689 689' }, 
            { id: 23, parent: 2, name: '0820 689 689' },
        ]
    },
],
```

});

Ext.define('Axiastats.view.NumbersChoicePanel', {
    extend   : 'Ext.FormPanel',
    renderTo: 'numbersChoice',
    alias    : 'widget.NumbersChoicePanel',
    id : 'numbersChoice-container',

```
requires : ['Ext.form.*','Ext.button.*', 'Ext.layout.container.Column', 'Ext.tab.Panel','Axiastats.store.Numbers'],

baseCls: 'numbersChoice-container',
cls: 'choice hoverBox round6',
layout: 'anchor',
bodyPadding: '0',
modal : true,
defaults: {
    border: false,
    layout: 'anchor',
},
items : [
    {
        xtype: 'box',
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'div',
            cls: 'arrow'
        }
    },
    {
        xtype: 'dataview',
        id: 'numbers-view',
        cls: 'cont round4',
        itemSelector: 'div.categNumbersRow',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
        //store: 'Axiastats.store.Numbers',
        tpl: [
            '<tpl for=".">',
                '<div class="close cat0{type} categNumbersRow" id="categNumbers-{id}">',
                    '<div id="theCategNumbers-{id}" class="title">',
                        '<span class="n01">{name}</span>',
                        '<span class="n02">',
                            '<input type="checkbox" id="checkCategNumbers-{id}" name="checkCategNumbers" value={id} checked="yes"/>',
                            '<label for="checkCategNumbers-{id}">La catégorie</label>',
                        '</span>',
                        '<span id="detailCategNumbers-{id}" class="n03">Détail</span>',
                        '<div class="clear"></div>',
                    '</div>',

                    '<div id="allNumbers-{id}" class="allNumbers" style="display:none;">',
                        '<span class="sep first"></span>',
                        '<ul>',
                            '<tpl for="children">',
                                '<li><input type="checkbox" id="numbersRow-{id}" name="numbersRow-{id}" value="{id}" class ="numbersRow"/> <label for="numbersRow-{id}">{name}</label></li>',
                            '</tpl>',
                        '</ul>',
                        '<span class="sep clear"></span>',
                        '<ul class="select">',
                            '<li><input type="checkbox" id="checkAllNumbers-{id}" name="checkAllNumbers-{id}" class="checkAllNumbers" value="{id}" /> <label for="checkAllNumbers-{id}">Sélectionner tout</label></li>',
                            '<li><input type="checkbox" id="checkAllNumbersReset-{id}" name="checkAllNumbersReset-{id}" class="checkAllNumbersReset" value="{id}" /> <label for="checkAllNumbersReset-{id}">Désélectionner</label></li>',
                        '</ul>',
                        '<span class="sep clear"></span>',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>',
            '</tpl>'
        ],
```

],

```
initComponent : function() {
    this.callParent();
},
```

});

But If I want to put my store external  in a file  like this :

```
Ext.define('Axiastats.store.Numbers', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
singleton : true,
autoLoad: true,
storeId:'employeeStore',
fields:['id', 'name', 'type','children'],
data:[
    {
        id : 1,
        name : "GEO ET 09",
        type : 1,
        children: [ 
            { id: 11, parent: 1 ,name: '0820 689 689' }, 
            { id: 12, parent: 1, name: '0820 689 689' },
            { id: 13, parent: 1 ,name: '0820 689 689' }, 
            { id: 14, parent: 1, name: '0820 689 689' },
        ]
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        name : "0800 & 0805",
        type : 2,
        children: [ 
            { id: 21, parent: 2, name: '0820 689 689' }, 
            { id: 22, parent: 2, name: '0820 689 689' }, 
            { id: 23, parent: 2, name: '0820 689 689' },
        ]
    },
],
```

});

And I remove store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'), by store: 'Axiastats.store.Numbers',

The store is loaded but the tpl is not loaded with it

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly create the store for the dataview: `store: Ext.create('Axiastats.store.Numbers')`.
Then remove the `singleton : true` config in the store. It will work as expected.